# Spring injection by type: two @Repository with same name

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, repository

I have this pair of daos:

```
package com.company.project.model.requests.type;

@Repository("requestTypeDao")
public class RequestTypeDaoHibernate extends AbstractReadDao implements RequestTypeDao {

}

package com.company.project.model.support.type;

@Repository("requestTypeDao")
public class RequestTypeDaoHibernate extends AbstractReadDao implements RequestTypeDao {

}
```

and I'm trying to inject them in some XXXServiceImpl classes (never both in the same class) like this:

```
@Autowired
private RequestTypeDao requestTypeDao;
```

Because they are not the same type, I was expecting Spring to inject based on the imported type from the corect package (there are never imported two RequestTypeDao from the same package), but it shows an error:

```
Annotation-specified bean name 'requestTypeDao' for bean class [com.company.project.model.support.type.RequestTypeDaoHibernate] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.company.project.model.requests.type.RequestTypeDaoHibernate]
```

At the error you can see the class is not the same. I have read about the @Qualifier annotation but I understand it would imply changing the name in written in the @Repository annotation. I also think that @Resource or @Inject are not what I looking for.

We don't mind changing names in the end, but we want to know if real injection by type can be made through Spring. This is two repositories with same name and different class types and packages being injected in distinct and different classes (never the same one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is impossible. There's no way to register two same named beans into the spring. You have to use `@Qualifier` Otherwise spring can't handle which bean you want in the runtime.

You can learn more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition.htm)

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("personA")
private Person person;



@Autowired
@Qualifier("personB")
private com.blabla.myOtherPackage.Person person;
```

Comment: Have you realized that I'm never putting those two declarations in same class? That does not change anything?

Comment: Indeed, this changes nothing. Spring uses bean definitions to register classes into it's dependency management system. In there names have to be unique. Please examine the link that I've wrote at the answer